# I want to fully understand what the ().velocity means after the <Rigidbody>

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

```
rightBat.GetComponent<Rigidbody>().velocity = new Vector3(0f, 8f, 0f);
```

Comment: It is documented. Read the doc [`Rigidbody.velocity`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Rigidbody-velocity.html)

Comment: It gives you the velocity vector of the object (or lets you set it)? Please clarify your question.

Comment: Yes i just dont understand why there is a (). before the velocity = new Vector3

Comment: because `GetComponent` is a method which returns a `Component`. You should definity read some basic tutorials about C# and programming.

Answer (score 3):

Well, `rightBat.GetComponent<T>()` is a generic method returning the component passed to it. In this case, that component is `Rigidbody`.
After that, you set the `velocity` property to a new `Vector`.

You could also use

```
Rigidbody foo = rightBat.GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
foo.velocity = new Vector(0f, 8f, 0f);
```

but in your case there is **no need to create the temporary variable** `foo` and so it's better to call it like

```
rightBat.GetComponent<Rigidbody>().velocity = new Vector(0f, 8f, 0f);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try to look at the expression above in a following way

```
((rightBat).GetComponent<Rigidbody>()).velocity = foo;
```

or, using different separators (this is not correct but maybe clearer visually)

```
[1]rightBat.[2]GetComponent<Rigidbody>()[3].velocity =[4] new Vector3();
```

[1] is your object (gameObject or another component)

[2] is a method (with generic syntax, hence the <>() madness)

[3] is a property setter 
[4] is a value